# Calendar where event dates can be added and deleted

Tags: javascript, html, calendar

[image]

I want to modify the calendar in the  index.html page of the free template 
[here](https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE)

I'm trying to add the ability to add and delete events in the calendar. What should I add to this particular fraction of code?

```
<li><a href="#">Add new event</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Clear events</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="#">View calendar</a></li>
```

The code for the calender is given below

```
 <div class="box box-solid bg-green-gradient">
      <div class="box-header ui-sortable-handle" style="cursor: move;">
          <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
              <h3 class="box-title">Calendar</h3>
              <!-- tools box -->
              <div class="pull-right box-tools">
                <!-- button with a dropdown -->
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Add new event</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Clear events</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">View calendar</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
              </div><!-- /. tools -->
            </div><!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body no-padding">
              <!--The calendar -->
              <div id="calendar" style="width: 100%"><div class="datepicker datepicker-inline"><div class="datepicker-days" style="display: block;"><table class="table table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev" style="visibility: visible;">«</th><th colspan="5" class="datepicker-switch">June 2015</th><th class="next" style="visibility: visible;">»</th></tr><tr><th class="dow">Su</th><th class="dow">Mo</th><th class="dow">Tu</th><th class="dow">We</th><th class="dow">Th</th><th class="dow">Fr</th><th class="dow">Sa</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td class="old day">31</td><td class="day">1</td><td class="day">2</td><td class="day">3</td><td class="day">4</td><td class="day">5</td><td class="day">6</td></tr><tr><td class="day">7</td><td class="day">8</td><td class="day">9</td><td class="day">10</td><td class="day">11</td><td class="day">12</td><td class="day">13</td></tr><tr><td class="day">14</td><td class="day">15</td><td class="day">16</td><td class="day">17</td><td class="day">18</td><td class="day">19</td><td class="day">20</td></tr><tr><td class="day">21</td><td class="day">22</td><td class="day">23</td><td class="day">24</td><td class="day">25</td><td class="day">26</td><td class="day">27</td></tr><tr><td class="day">28</td><td class="day">29</td><td class="day">30</td><td class="new day">1</td><td class="new day">2</td><td class="new day">3</td><td class="new day">4</td></tr><tr><td class="new day">5</td><td class="new day">6</td><td class="new day">7</td><td class="new day">8</td><td class="new day">9</td><td class="new day">10</td><td class="new day">11</td></tr></tbody><tfoot><tr><th colspan="7" class="today" style="display: none;">Today</th></tr><tr><th colspan="7" class="clear" style="display: none;">Clear</th></tr></tfoot></table></div><div class="datepicker-months" style="display: none;"><table class="table table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev" style="visibility: visible;">«</th><th colspan="5" class="datepicker-switch">2015</th><th class="next" style="visibility: visible;">»</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td colspan="7"><span class="month">Jan</span><span class="month">Feb</span><span class="month">Mar</span><span class="month">Apr</span><span class="month">May</span><span class="month">Jun</span><span class="month">Jul</span><span class="month">Aug</span><span class="month">Sep</span><span class="month">Oct</span><span class="month">Nov</span><span class="month">Dec</span></td></tr></tbody><tfoot><tr><th colspan="7" class="today" style="display: none;">Today</th></tr><tr><th colspan="7" class="clear" style="display: none;">Clear</th></tr></tfoot></table></div><div class="datepicker-years" style="display: none;"><table class="table table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev" style="visibility: visible;">«</th><th colspan="5" class="datepicker-switch">2010-2019</th><th class="next" style="visibility: visible;">»</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td colspan="7"><span class="year old">2009</span><span class="year">2010</span><span class="year">2011</span><span class="year">2012</span><span class="year">2013</span><span class="year">2014</span><span class="year">2015</span><span class="year">2016</span><span class="year">2017</span><span class="year">2018</span><span class="year">2019</span><span class="year new">2020</span></td></tr></tbody><tfoot><tr><th colspan="7" class="today" style="display: none;">Today</th></tr><tr><th colspan="7" class="clear" style="display: none;">Clear</th></tr></tfoot></table></div></div></div>
            </div><!-- /.box-body -->
            <div class="box-footer text-black">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <!-- Progress bars -->
                  <div class="clearfix">
                    <span class="pull-left">Task #1</span>
                    <small class="pull-right">90%</small>
                  </div>
                  <div class="progress xs">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-green" style="width: 90%;"></div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="clearfix">
                    <span class="pull-left">Task #2</span>
                    <small class="pull-right">70%</small>
                  </div>
                  <div class="progress xs">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-green" style="width: 70%;"></div>
                  </div>
                </div><!-- /.col -->
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="clearfix">
                    <span class="pull-left">Task #3</span>
                    <small class="pull-right">60%</small>
                  </div>
                  <div class="progress xs">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-green" style="width: 60%;"></div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="clearfix">
                    <span class="pull-left">Task #4</span>
                    <small class="pull-right">40%</small>
                  </div>
                  <div class="progress xs">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-green" style="width: 40%;"></div>
                  </div>
                </div><!-- /.col -->
              </div><!-- /.row -->
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question, it is unclear.

Comment: @odedta what is not clear pls tell me i will make it clear

Comment: What exactly you want to do and don't succeed?

Comment: i want to add event to a particular date, but in the given calendar if i click on "Add event " option of the dropdown menu it redirect me to same page
so what should be the code so that i am able to select a date and add event to it

Comment: Are you using a plugin to render this calendar? if so, which plugin?

Comment: bootstrap-datepicker,daterangepicker

Comment: This one? http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81115/discussion-between-udaykumarverma-and-odedta).

Comment: i am not sure , i am trying to modify a free template i told u the name from the plugin links given in the code , the template link is here ,this calender is in the index.html page 
https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE,

Comment: i've modified the calender witch can be found here: http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.3.2/demos/external-dragging.html. Maybe it's helpful to start over. --- its not my modification, just the used calendar.

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, please edit your question to include your code and research to show what hasn't worked for you. If you haven't, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Answer (score 0):

The links for 'Add new event' and 'Clear events' will just lead you to the top of the page which is indicated when you say href="#". Perhaps you should look into adding a function so when 'Add new event' is clicked something happens. It would look similiar to this:

```
<li onclick="myFunction()>Add new event</li>
```

Or maybe you want to take the user to a new page:

```
<a href="myNewPage.html">Add new event</a>
```